# Call asynchronous Stream's CopyToAsync and have Error -4077 ECONNRESET connection reset by peer

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, asp.net-core, .net-core

I run my application and it throws exception here, at the `await` call:

```
var dumpRequest = new MemoryStream();
await context.Request.Body.CopyToAsync(dumpRequest);
```

Anybody knows the reason and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It means the client disconnected during the copy. What would you expect to happen if the client disconnects while you were reading?

Comment: Hi @davidfowl, thanks for kind of clue. If that is as your saying, I don't know why the client disconnected. The browser is still open during process. Do you have any experience for the possible reasons? Thanks

Comment: be prepared to get a lot of these on your site as it's quite a normal way for hackers to crash a site and has nothing to do with preventing you to copy the request